# How to add index.html link in Jenkins dashboard?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng, dashboard

I am using Selenium(2.47.1) & TestNG(testng-6.8.5.jar) framework.I'm using Jenkins for continuous integration. Jenkins is installed in Linux server. I want to add index.html(present inside test-output directory) file link in Jenkins Dashboard as shown in below screenshot.. How to do this??

[image]

How to add test-output/index.html link into Jenkins Dashboard as shown in above screenshot?

Comment: The arrow to the _Changes_ is actually a link to the Changes, that took place in the Source Control System (cvs, subversion, git, etc). What kind of build system are you using: Ant / Maven / Gradle ?

Comment: I don't want to modify Changes. I want to add New Link called Test_Output to that List below Delete Build. I am using TestNG only..

Comment: Ok, now clear what the actual question is. Not sure there is a possibility to modify the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

**Maven**

When using Maven as build system, then the [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) will run the TestNG tests and create the HTML output. Jenkins then automatically known where these test results are placed (within the `target` directory).

**Show any HTML in Jenkins build**

In case some other build tool is used, or some configuration which is not automaticaaly correctly seen by Jenkins, there is always the [HTML Publisher Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) which can show any HTML report in the Jenkins build job view.

**Improve Jenkins Side Bar**

These Jenkins plug-ins provide a way to add extra entries in the Side Bar.

- [Sidebar Link Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin)
- [Anchor Chain Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnchorChain+plugin)

Comment: I have tried HTML Publisher Plugin. But I can't able to add New Link to index.html to the Drop-Down showed in screenshot..